# Closing an application (a CAD viewer), that blocks code execution, from within the code

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Hi stackoverflow community!
I'm trying to write a piece of code that loops through CAD files and takes pictures of them. The problem that I encounter is that I have to open the CAD files in a viewer in order to take the pictures and this viewer blocks the further execution of code until I close it. I want to automate the process of picture taking and I thought that it would be possible to start the viewer in a separate process and then close it, but as I'm rather a beginner in python multiprocessing/threading, I struggle to do that. That's the code that I'm using:

```
from OCC.Core.STEPControl import STEPControl_Reader
from OCC.Display.SimpleGui import init_display


def load_step(filepath):
    ....
    return step_reader.Shape()


for i in range(1191,2000):
    
    folder = '00000000' + str(i)
    folder_path = "E:/CAD/" + folder[-8:]
    file_name = os.listdir(folder_path)
    file_path = folder_path+'/'+file_name[0]
    body = load_step(file_path)
    picture1 = './' + folder[-8:] + '_n.png'
    picture2 = './' + folder[-8:] + '_r.png'
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        display, start_display, add_menu, add_function_to_menu = init_display()
        display.DisplayShape(body, update=True)
        display.View.Dump(picture1)
        display.View.Rotate(0,1.2,0)
        display.View.Dump(picture2)
        start_display() #starts the viewer
        #  close the viewer
```

So the question is: is there a way to close the viewer automatically from within the python code?

Comment: There should be. I'm not sure about the exact python commands but if you can iterate through all the processes in system and find the viewer, you should be able to close it. Since whatever library you are using already has a "start_display", there should be something to stop it? Or dispose/kill/clear/flush/close? Maybe some digging will help you.

Comment: What you're asking is very specific to the OCC library since `init_display()` is from their code (in SimpleGui.py), and is not a general python command.  I'd suggest that you dig through their code / examples and if you can't find what you're looking for, post the question to that librarie's GitHub issues list.